# Javascript OnChange for Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onchange

I have 5 checkboxes and 1 textarea in my form and would like to just hook OnChange() for all of these. However, for whatever reason nothing I have found on Stack Overflow seems to be getting called.

As this is the most basic example I found, what is wrong with this?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input").on("input", function()
    {
        alert("CHANGED");
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, it does not work on a `textarea`, `input` != `textarea`. Try `$("input, textarea").on("change", function() { alert("changed"); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oninput` event is only triggered when the **text** of an input changes, so it won't be fired for checkboxes. Try binding to the `change` event for checkboxes and the `input` event on textareas:

```
$("textarea").on("input", yourFunction);
$("input:checkbox").on("change", yourFunction);

function yourFunction() {
    alert("CHANGED");
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4qM8/) which demonstrates the above.

*Note*: The difference in this answer is the `alert` is triggered immediately in the `textarea`, not only on blur of the element.

*Additional Note*: The `oninput` event isn't supported in < IE9

Comment: Should this be placed in document ready? Something is strange as nothing is happening at all.

Comment: @BrettPowell Yup, needs to be in the document ready for it to work (as shown in the fiddle)

Comment: That worked, thank you. Seems I forgot a ) and it was causing my Document.Ready function not to work lol. How can I get the element name/value for the checkbox inside this function?

Answer (score 3):

you should handle change event:

```
$('input:checkbox,textarea').change(function () {
   alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: What about the textarea?

Comment: @putvande add elements selectors you want to trigger functions

Answer (score 1):

Why you bind `input` event for checkbox, it's only fire for textarea?

You need to bind `change` event :

Try this one:

**Updated**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("textarea").on("input", function(){
      alert("CHANGED");
    });

    $("input").on("change", function(){
        alert("CHANGED");
    });
});
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mT5z/3/)

Comment: No, both are in a single "document ready"( Due to bad alingment they look like). :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes usually used with same name property so in selector name property will be usefull

```
$("input[name='interests']").change(function(){
   /*some code*/
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It will not work on textarea . you can assign all radio button and textarea a same class and then

```
$(".your_class_name").on("change", function()
{
    alert("CHANGED");
});
```